# Display Y-axis in Stacked Column Chart using Google Charts

Tags: jquery, charts, google-visualization, stacked-chart, yaxis

I'm using google charts to display my stacked chart.My x-axis is numeric and y-axis is also numeric. I'm getting a black line as x-axis.But the y-axis is missing. It is not displayed.

I have tried below mentioned property, but it didn't work:

```
 vAxis: {
      baseline: 0,
    }
```

What property needs to be set in order to display Y-axis.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/crazyCoder1989/8p6z4631/122/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the view window placed on the x-axis is hiding / overriding the baseline...

```
hAxis: {
  viewWindow: {
    min: min,
    max: max
  }
  ...
```

changing the min to zero, allows the baseline to appear...

```
var min = 0;
var max = data.getColumnRange(0).max;
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages:['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Machine', '', {
      role: 'style'
    }, '', {
      role: 'style'
    }, '', {
      role: 'style'
    }, '', {
      role: 'style'
    }, ''],
    [0.5, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, 0.067],
    [1, 0.05, "#808080", 0.0775, "#C71585", 0.069, "#FFC0CB", 0.05, "Blue", 0.067],
    [2, 0.05, "Yellow", 0.0775, "Pink", 0.069, "#808080", 0.05, "Green", 0.067],
    [2.5, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, 0.067]
  ]);

  var min = 0;
  var max = data.getColumnRange(0).max;

  var options = {
    width: 500,
    height: 500,
    legend: {
      position: 'none',
      maxLines: 6,
      textStyle: {
        color: 'black',
        fontSize: 10
      }
    },
    isStacked: true,
    seriesType: 'bars',
    series: {
      4: {
        type: "line",
        color: '#FF0000',
        visibleInLegend: false
      }

    },
    hAxis: {
      ticks: [{
        "v": 1,
        "f": "M1"
      }, {
        "v": 2,
        "f": "M2"
      }],
      viewWindow: {
        min: min,
        max: max
      }
    }
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.The Y-axis did appear after changing the min to 0. But the red series line(horizontal line) is not touching the Y-axis after this change.How to solve that?

Comment: I have solved this. I made the lowest value to 0 --->  
[0, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, 0.067],